# Hide typedef implementatation

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I have this *typedef* that depend from a type in another library (boost in this case):

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>

typedef boost::any& myAnyType;
```

I would use the definition *myAnyType* in all my programs hiding its real nature and keeping independence from Boost library (the client does not need to install Boost to use myAnyType)

It is possible?

Answer (score 2):

> the client does not need to install Boost to use myAnyType

It most certainly does. Yes, you define this as a reference to an `any`, so they can declare a "myAnyType" variable without a definition for the type. But they can't do anything with it. Indeed, something as simple as `myAnyType var;` fails, because it's a reference.

They can't even call functions that takes `myAnyType` as a parameter, because they cannot declare a `myAnyType` object. Even a `const myAnyType` wouldn't work, because C++ would have to create a temporary. And it can't create a temporary from an undefined type.

Your library is not independent of Boost; it *relies* on Boost, and it puts Boost in its interface. `myAnyType` is a part of Boost, because it is based on something that is a part of Boost. Your clients are therefore clients of Boost. The sooner you and they accept that, the better.

Comment: I tend to agree, with one note though: If you design your library so that _the only way_ to instantiate objects of `myAnyType` is through a _factory function_ provided by your library, then all the _user_ ever needs to know is `myAnyType *` - which you can, on the user-visible side, just as well `typedef void*` then. Nothing wrong with that (unless you consider the use of pointers in C++ "wrong").

Comment: @FrankH.: But it's a `boost::any`. The point of that type is that it could be *any* object. It's a type-checked `void*`. There would be no point in creating them by factory functions.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible, as the compiler needs to see the complete definition of your type in order to instantiate it in the client program. Thus, the boost headers need to be available.

Answer (score 0):

if it's just a typedef, you can get by using a forward declaration *if there is zero physical dependence*. to illustrate:

```
namespace MON {
class t_hidden_type; // << the forward
typedef t_hidden_type& t_opaque_type_ref; // << the typedef
}
```

this way, inclusion is not required.

of course, you can also wrap the hidden type if you *really* need to hide the implementation -- this will also rename the binary symbols.

```
namespace MON {
class myAnyType; // in the public interface
}

namespace MON {
namespace Private {
// in the private/package interface
class myAnyType {
  ...
  boost::any d_any;
};
}
}
```